# Javascript/jQuery: Get key by value inside a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
var myJSON =     
{"data":
    [{"obj1":"value1",
      "obj2":"value2"},

     {"obj1":"value3",
      "obj2":"value4"},

     {"obj1":"value5",
      "obj2":"value6"}]
};
```

I've got a multidimensional array similar to above. In the above example I can get `value4` by calling `data[1].obj2` - the key would be `1` in this case.

My problem: I've got `value4` but I don't where it is inside the array (in terms of the key). I know `value4` belongs to `obj2` and I need to find it's corresponding `obj1`.

I'm guessing the way to solve this is to figure out what the `i` should be in `data[i]` for `value4` and then simply call `data[i].obj1`. But how do I get that `i`?

Comment: This is not a multidimensional array. What you have is a simple array with 3 objects inside

Comment: It's a bit abstract with this mock data, but in general you should be able to loop through the array and validate for each item if the value in `"obj1"` is the one you need and in that case get the corresponding `"obj2"` and break the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm guessing the way to solve this is to figure out what the `i` should be in `data[i]` for `value4` and then simply call `data[i].obj1`.

`obj2`, you mean, not `obj1`.

> But how do I get that `i`?

You search for it. It's a simple loop.

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myJSON.data.length; ++i) {
    if (myJSON.data[i].obj2 === "value4") {
        // Found it
        break;
    }
}
if (i < myJSON.data.length) {
    // Found it, it's at index `i`
}
```

Or on a system where you can rely on ES5's `forEach` (either because the engine has it natively, or because you've added a shim):

```
var i;
myJSON.data.forEach(function(entry, index) {
    if (entry.obj2 === "value4") {
        i = index;
    }
};
if (typeof i !== "undefined") {
    // Found it
}
```

You can't stop a `forEach` early, so that does some unnecessary looping. You could use `some`:

```
var i;
myJSON.data.some(function(entry, index) {
    if (entry.obj2 === "value4") {
        i = index;
        return true; // Stops loop
    }
};
if (typeof i !== "undefined") {
    // Found it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple recursive function:

```
find = function(where, what) {
    if (typeof where != "object")
        return null;
    var matches = true;
    for (var p in what)
        matches = matches && (where[p] == what[p]);
    if (matches)
        return where;
    for (var p in where) {
        var found = find(where[p], what);
        if(found)
            return found;
    }
    return null;
}
```

It works with objects of any depth and allows for multiple search keys. For your example:

```
var data = {"data":
        [{"obj1":"value1",
            "obj2":"value2"},

            {"obj1":"value3",
                "obj2":"value4"},

            {"obj1":"value5",
                "obj2":"value6"}]
};

result = find(data, {"obj2":"value4"})
console.log(result.obj1) // value3
```

Another (and nicer) way to do the same is to provide a test predicate for the finder function:

```
find = function(where, test) {
    if (test(where))
        return where;
    if (typeof where != "object")
        return null;
    for (var p in where) {
        var found = find(where[p], test);
        if (found)
            return found;
    }
    return null;
}

result = find(data, function(x) { return x.obj2 == "value4" });
```

Comment: interesting approach, but the point is the OP doesn't even know `obj2`.  The desired result in this case would be the list of keys - `['data', 1, 'obj2']`.

Comment: @Alnitak: yes, the question is a bit unclear... let the OP clarify.

Comment: ah, yes - it seems the OP does indeed know `obj2` - my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to manually trawl through your object:

```
for(var a=0; a<myJSON.data.length; a++)
{
 for(var b in myJSON.data[a])
 {
  if(myJSON.data[a][b]=="value4")
  {
   console.log("myJSON["+a+"]."+b)
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to revise the entire data-structure, but assume that this is an abstracted example.

```
for(var ei in myJSON["data"]){
    if (myJSON["data"][ei]['obj2'] == "value4")){
      //ei contains the key
      //do something & break;
    }
}
```

Here is one-liner, although slower:

```
myJSON["data"].map(function(e,i){if(e["obj2"]=="value4")return e;}).filter(Boolean)[0];
```

or for the key:

```
myJSON["data"].map(function(e,i){if(e["obj2"]=="value4")return i;}).filter(Number)[0];
```

Also see `T.J. Crowder`s answer using `some` - still slow but avoiding unnecessary cycles.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then you could use the [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) function to perform your search:

```
var searchValue = "value4";

var result = $.grep(myJSON.data, function (e) { 
        return e.obj2 === searchValue;
    });

console.log(result[0].obj1);
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/m60n65vy/) for a working example.