# Extracting a selection of countries from JSON file

Tags: d3.js, geojson

I'm using this great example: [Countries By Area](http://www.jasondavies.com/maps/countries-by-area/)

However I'm wanting to modify this code for my own use and project only a selection of chosen countries.

I've managed to read the JSON file into an array, and the code is now looking through that array but I don't see any way on rendering a country (or countries) if a criteria is met.

For example, if I want to simply render the country, who has an ID of 533, I don't see any way of attaching a condition.

Can anyone shed any light on how I may be able to do this.

Have edited my original question here as I've managed to do it, but I'm sure there's a more elegant way of achieving it:

Original code was:

```
  var svg = d3.select("#map").selectAll("svg")
      .data(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features)
```

Which I've changed to:

```
            var svg = chartDetails.plotArea.selectAll("svg")
            .data(
            function(d){
                a = topojson.feature(tempWorld, tempWorld.objects.countries).features
                var returnobject =[]
                $.each(a, function (i, v) { if (v.id == 826) { returnobject.push(v) } });
                return returnobject
            })
```

- 826 refers to United Kingdom.

Answer (score 0):

If your array looks like this:

```
var a = [];
a.push({id:1, name:'Argentina'});
a.push({id:2, name:'Bahamas'});
```

Then you might need to iterate it to find the key(id) you want.
Take a look at these [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888744/javascript-jquery-get-key-by-value-inside-a-nested-array):

Comment: Hi, thanks, but not exactly what I meant, have changed my code to highlight the issue.

Comment: I see. One small thing you could do is to make(filter by id) your `returnedobject` outside of the svg and then pass into `.data(retrunedobject)`.  This will make the code more reusable.